# Why is my domain prefixed to the value of href of <a> and/or the url of window.Open()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, hyperlink, tags

Every so often (1/20) I use to have issues with the `href` value of a hyperlink being prefixed with my domain. Same goes for the url of `window.open()`.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.SomeURL.com" target="_blank">someURL</a>
```

OR

```
window.Open('http://www.SomeURL.com', '', '');
```

would open up a new browser tab and give me a 404 with the requested url of:
http://www.myDomain.com/http://www.SomeURL.com

As a work-around, I have my 404 error page get the requested url and if the requested url contains http://www.myDomain, I slice it then try to redirect again without my domain prefixed. I am guessing there is an actual solution to this though?

 
**additional info**
I have a gridView that list activities- some fields being: name, address, website ...etc. I use jQuery to get the URL of the gridView row that was clicked. I then insert that URL into a hyperlink inside of a span that is already on my page. 

**jQuery**
      var str = $("td:last", this).text();
       $ ("#urlInfoLocation").html('< a id="urlLocation" target="_blank" href="' + str + '">' + str + ''); 

**the span that is already on my page**
    < span id="urlInfo">

Comment: Can you check on other browsers or other computers if have the same issue - maybe a browser plugin cause this - or check if the `http://` is NOT Url encoded ! You can see that on the html source.

Comment: This happens if you don't put http:// at the beginning of your url, but you have it. Can you try to use backslash?

Comment: Well actually if it happens when you don't put http:// then that is most likely what it is. Why is this? I am working with data that did not have very good validation before being entered into the database, so who knows what string is being pulled as a URL. I recall seeing a few URL's in the database without http://.

Comment: Because on your question you include the http:// I say that maybe is encoded. But if not exist you see that `http://www.myDomain.com/www.SomeURL.com`

Comment: can you please put actual code line here and the redirecting url. just copy a line from source.

Comment: Yep, I looked for a URL without http:// and got a 404 so that is what it is. I still don't understand this though. If I open a new browser tab and enter www.google.com, google loads, but when I click a hyperlink from my website that has an href value of www.google, I get a 404. Does this have to do with cross-domain issues?

Comment: No, just with how HTML works. If a link doesn't start with a valid scheme (http:), the link is assumed to be relative to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is you entered a unicode Right or Left Double Quotation Mark. Here's an example I found in my own page"

<a href=”https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txLrNhv8GW0”>Q&A on Zone 2 Exercise with Peter Attia, M.D.

Just replace with a normal double quote.

[Q&A on Zone 2 Exercise with Peter Attia, M.D.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txLrNhv8GW0)